# Another martingale solution to the ABRACADABRA problem

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

A monkey is typing out uniform and independent random letters. Let $T$ be the first time at which it's typed out ABRACADABRA. What is $E(T)$?

You can read the standard solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672252/monkey-typing-abracadabra-and-gamblers). Here's mine. Rather than having new gamblers join the game at every stage, just have one gambler. He starts with 1 dollar, and bets that dollar the next letter will be A. If it is, he wins 26 dollars and bets it all the next letter will be B, and so on - each time he bets it all, and each time, if we wins, he gets 26 times his wager. If he ever loses, he goes back to 1 dollar *and keeps playing*.

Let $X_n$ be the amount of money after $n$ after $n$ games, so $X_0=1$.

$$E(X_{n+1}|X_n)=\frac{1}{26} 26 X_n + \frac{25}{26} 1$$

So that $X_n - \frac{25}{26}n$ is a martingale with bounded increments ($X_{n+1} - X_n$ is bounded by something on the order of $26^{11}$) and it can be shown that $E(T)$ is finite. Thus

$$E(X_T-\frac{25}{26}T)=1$$
$$E(T)=\frac{26}{25}(E(X_T) - 1)=\frac{26}{25}(26^{11} - 1)$$

This is not the correct answer. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It seems this neglects that, for example, after ABRA, if the monkey types B instead of C, one should not start all over again by betting 1 since one already has the prefix AB of the desired word ABRACADABRA hence the correct bet would be 4 (if I understand correctly the logic of the procedure you are suggesting).

Comment: @Did You're right. The specific step that's wrong is $X_T=26^{11}$. If the sequence goes ABRABRACADABRA, then $X_T=26^4$.