# Generalized $\texttt{ABRACADABRA}$ Problem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, permutations, game-theory, martingales

Consider the classic problem of a monkey hitting random keys on a keyboard, each with equal probability, and calculating the expected time for the monkey to type $\texttt{ABRACADABRA}$ (if unfamiliar with the martingale solution see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672252/monkey-typing-abracadabra-and-gamblers)).

Is there a straightforward way to extend the solution to an arbitrary alphabet, arbitrary distribution of hitting the keys on the alphabet, and arbitrary string?

### Edit

Based on Misha Lavrov's and user6247850's answers and comments. Let $A$ be an alphabet, $p$ be a probability distribution over the characters of this alphabet and $S$ be a string, with $s_i$ the $i$-th character. Let $p(s_i)$ be the probability of hitting this character.

I define $L_n(S)$ the left substring of $S$ of length $n$ by the first $n$ characters of $S$, and analogously $R_n(S)$ the right substring of $S$ of length $n$ by the last $n$ characters of $S$.

The expectation of the stopping time $T_S$ will be:

$$\mathbb{E}(T_S) = \sum_{i=1}^{\#S}\left(\prod_{j=1}^i p(s_j)^{-1}\right)\mathbf{1}(R_i(S) = L_i(S)),$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the indicator function. Is this correct?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Can people excited about the new option of giving anonymous feedback on questions please *be better at getting it right*? This is a perfectly specific problem with the right amount of detail.

Comment: [An empirical experiment](https://web.archive.org/web/20090318143423/http://www.vivaria.net/experiments/notes/publication/NOTES_EN.pdf) suggested that monkeys do not type successive letters independently of the previous letter.

Comment: @Henry Interesting, but I don't see how this is relevant to the problem posed... Clearly, the monkey is just a theoretical construct to give some "flavor" to the problem :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generalization to arbitrary alphabet and arbitrary string does not take much additional work. For an alphabet of size $k$ and an arbitrary string $s_1 s_2 \dots s_t$:

- once again we have a gambler appear before every keystroke and wager $\$1$ on the next letter being $s_1$, winning $\$k$ if they are right.
- once again, every gambler that wins proceeds to bet all their money on the next letter being $s_2$; then bet all their money on the next letter being $s_3$, and so on.

The bets are all fair (expected value $0$). After $N$ keystrokes, there are $N$ gamblers, who start with $\$N$ total, so the expected amount they end with is also $\$N$. This remains the same in expectation if $N$ is a stopping time, such as the time when the string $s_1s_2 \dots s_t$ first appears.

At this stopping time, one lucky gambler has won $\$k^t$. Also, for all $0<i<t$, if the string's first $i$ letters are equal to its last $i$ letters (if $s_1 s_2 \dots s_i = s_{t-i+1} s_{t-i+2} \dots s_t$)  then another gambler has won $\$k^i$. This tells us the total amount of money anyone has at time $N$, so it must also tell us the expected value of time $N$.

Some special cases:

- The word $\texttt{ALFALFA}$ first appears at time $k^7 + k^4 + k$ in expectation.
- The word $\texttt{AAA...AA}$ of length $t$ first appears at time $k^t + k^{t-1} + \dots + k = \frac{k^{t+1}-k}{k-1}$ in expectation.
- Most words (including, but not limited to words with no repeated letters) first appear at time $k^t$ in expectation.

---

To generalize to arbitrary probabilities, we need to adjust the payoffs to make the game fair. Suppose that the string is still $s_1 s_2 \dots s_t$, but now letter $s_i$ has probability $p_i$ of occurring. Betting on a letter with probability $p$ should get a gambler $\frac1p$ dollars for every dollar they bet. Therefore the final gambler's winnings are $(p_1 p_2 \dotsm p_t)^{-1}$, and for every overlap $s_1 s_2 \dots s_i = s_{t-i+1} s_{t-i+2} \dots s_t$, there is another gambler with winnings $(p_1 p_2 \dotsm p_i)^{-1}$. The sum of these is the expected time until the string appears.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just adjust the payoff for each letter to make the wagers fair.  For example, if the probability of hitting $a$ is $p_a$, then the payoff for betting $\$1$ on $a$ should be $\frac{1}{p_a}$.  The analysis for finding the total payoff works the same, but is probably slightly messier.  For example, if the string is "abab," the first gambler wins $\frac{1}{p_a^2p_b^2}$ and the gambler that started with the second $a$ wins $\frac{1}{p_a p_b}$, so the expected time before "abab" is spelled is $\frac{1}{p_a^2p_b^2} + \frac{1}{p_a p_b}$.

Comment: I believe the right approach would be: Let $S$ be the string. Let $L_n(S)$ be the left-slice of string $s$ with length $n$, i.e., the **first** $n$ characters of string $n$. Analogously, let $R_n(S)$ be the right-slice of string $s$ with length $n$, i.e., the **last** $n$ characters of string $s$. If all characters have the same probability, let $A$ be the alphabet. The expected time will be:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\# S} (\# A)^i \mathbf{1}\{R_i(S) = L_i(S)\}$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function.

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to code it up, that looks like it would work.